# How to display a tree in python similar to msdos tree command?

Tags: python, tree

Consider this mcve:

```
import sys


dct = {
    -1: [0, 60000],
    0: [100, 20],
    100: [30],
    30: [400, 500],
    60000: [70, 80]
}


def ptree(parent, tree, indent=''):
    print(parent)
    if parent not in tree:
        return

    for child in tree[parent][:-1]:
        print(indent + '|' + '-' * 4, end='')
        ptree(child, tree, indent + '|' + ' ' * 4)
    child = tree[parent][-1]
    print(indent + '`' + '-' * 4, end='')
    ptree(child, tree, indent + '  ' * 4)


ptree(-1, dct)
```

There are 2 issues with this little code:

- Item -1 is considered in this context the "invisible root item", therefore I don't want to print it
- The output of this command is really ugly and also is bad-aligned, I'd like to get a similar output than the one displayed by [tree](https://www.computerhope.com/treehlp.htm)

In order to address the first bulletpoint I've thought about introducing these ugly conditions/hacks to the code:

```
def ptree(parent, tree, indent=''):
    if parent != -1:
        print(parent)
    if parent not in tree:
        return

    for child in tree[parent][:-1]:
        if parent != -1:
            print(indent + '|' + '-' * 4, end='')
            ptree(child, tree, indent + '|' + ' ' * 4)
        else:
            ptree(child, tree, indent)
    child = tree[parent][-1]
    if parent != -1:
        print(indent + '`' + '-' * 4, end='')
        ptree(child, tree, indent + '  ' * 4)
    else:
        ptree(child, tree, indent)
```

For the 2nd bulletpoint I don't know very well how to achieve it but the output displayed by msdos tree command is really nice and I'd like my command to display the tree exactly in the same way, here's an example of what command will look like:

[image]

**QUESTION**: How would you tweak the above code so it'll address properly the 2 mentioned bulletpoints?

Comment: Are you interested in getting something that works, or in figuring out how to write it yourself? Because there are a bunch of libraries on PyPI that already do things like this. I vaguely remember using one named something like `asciitree` (which might be [this one](https://pypi.org/project/asciitree/), but I don't think it is; I remember having options to specify which set of line drawing characters to use…), and you can search for others.

Comment: `treelib` module looks promising [docs](https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#basic-usage) , [code example](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib/blob/master/examples/recursive_dirtree_generator.py)

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about `asciitree`, it _does_ have the options I remember. See [Fancier examples in the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/asciitree/).

Comment: Guys, thanks for the links to those libraries, tomorrow I'll definitely check them out, I usually like to figure out how to write this kind of stuff by myself but in this case I really don't mind to use something that just works out of the box. The main precondition is the solution provides an output pleasant to work with, I'll be working with processes trees and my first thought was that an output such as the one provided by msdos tree command was quite eye-pleasant because of the lines being continuous (non distracting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through trial and error I somehow ended up with a solution that seems to spit out exactly what original tree produces:

```
def ptree(start, tree, indent_width=4):

    def _ptree(start, parent, tree, grandpa=None, indent=""):
        if parent != start:
            if grandpa is None:  # Ask grandpa kids!
                print(parent, end="")
            else:
                print(parent)
        if parent not in tree:
            return
        for child in tree[parent][:-1]:
            print(indent + "├" + "─" * indent_width, end="")
            _ptree(start, child, tree, parent, indent + "│" + " " * 4)
        child = tree[parent][-1]
        print(indent + "└" + "─" * indent_width, end="")
        _ptree(start, child, tree, parent, indent + " " * 5)  # 4 -> 5

    parent = start
    print(start)
    _ptree(start, parent, tree)


dct = {
    -1: [0, 60000],
    0: [100, 20, 10],
    100: [30],
    30: [400, 500],
    60000: [70, 80, 600],
    500: [495, 496, 497]
}
```

Besides using the right connectors, checking for grandpa and increasing indent from 4 to 5 for the last ptree-call was key.

---

```
ptree(-1, dct)
# Out
├────0
│    ├────100
│    │    └────30
│    │         ├────400
│    │         └────500
│    │              ├────495
│    │              ├────496
│    │              └────497
│    ├────20
│    └────10
└────60000
     ├────70
     ├────80
     └────600
```

Comment: @darknoaut Awesome! I really like this answer. Both ascitree and treelib were good candidates but didn't figure out how to skip the root node. Prune's answer was good but it was missing the continuous lines. Plus, in comparison, I think this one is really convenient to work with, I think having fixed-width levels has few advantages. So yeah, thanks ;)

Comment: Btw, it seems the algorithm won't print properly the tree when using values !=-1, ie: try displaying the tree of these values `0,100,30,500,60000` to see what I [mean](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/caqjtxu6bfxsm91/sublime_text_2018-08-19_22-32-06.png)

Comment: You mean changing the starting node value from -1 to another value? Did you change the value in this line also: `if parent != -1:` ?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Btw, I guess the public signature should turn out into something more like `def ptree(parent, tree, key, level)` where key will be a filtering function and level a parametrization of `4` and `5` constant values.  If you think about it, `grandpa` and `indent` are just private variables, therefore shouldn't be exposed to the user. Anyway, thanks again to point it out

Comment: You're right, a wrapper for that would make sense, not just for that. Also adding a start-value parameter if you want to zoom in so you don't have to change code...I'll make that last one right now.

Comment: @BPL Ok think we have it :) You're aware this will break with duplicates? You're  data-structure doesn't resemble the tree you're building. Was wondering how you ended up with this approach all the time because you usually would expect a nested dict with the exact level of nesting for the tree you're going to build.

Comment: Here's a last touch for your [code](https://bpaste.net/show/8eb2680ce290)... And about duplicates, that's a good remark (it'll produce RecursionError exceptions) although for my particular case I'm not really worried as this code will be basically used to display processes identifier (pid) trees, which are basically sets. I'd give you another thumb-up but I can't as I did already ;) . tyvm

Comment: Reasonable addition, just added it with a less ambiguous name, got your intention with "level" wrong at first glance. Thanks for asking, already voted up, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is simple: check the parent value; if it's -1, don't print it.

The indentation amount is a matter of shifting according to the print image of the node's value, rather than a constant 4 spaces.  the `math` package has `log10` and `ceil` methods that do the job.

```
import sys
import math


dct = {
    -1: [0, 60000],
    0: [100, 20, 7],
    100: [30],
    30: [400, 500],
    60000: [70, 80],
    7: [9, 11, 13],
}


def ptree(parent, tree, indent=''):

    if parent != -1:
        print(parent)

    if parent not in tree:
        return

    shift = math.ceil(math.log10(parent)) \
            if parent >= 10 else 1
    indent += ' ' * shift

    for child in tree[parent][:-1]:
        print(indent + '|' + '-' * 4, end='')
        ptree(child, tree, indent + '|' + ' ' * 4)

    child = tree[parent][-1]
    print(indent + '`' + '-' * 4, end='')
    ptree(child, tree, indent + ' ' * 4)


ptree(-1, dct)
```

Output:

```
 |----0
 |     |----100
 |     |      `----30
 |     |            |----400
 |     |            `----500
 |     |----20
 |     `----7
 |          |----9
 |          |----11
 |          `----13
 `----60000
          |----70
          `----80
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, certainly this is an interesting approach, at first I was thinking a fixed-width indentation such as the one provided by the msdos tree command was really eye-pleasant but your method doesn't look that bad either, does it? Btw, would you know which characters is using the msdos tree command instead of the {'`', '-', '|'} character set? That way the tree lines would look continuous. Tomorrow I'll test your answer thoroughly with long nested trees to check how it feels in comparison to a fixed-width indentation approach, +1 for the time being.